#  Looking for an html element/property that shows a line of text when it is clicked on (not a popup)

Tags: html, properties

These elements/properties should be able to be highlighted when hovered over. When clicked on, they should display a small box(not a popup) of information(only 1 line needed).

I thought about the link element but I don't want it to link anywhere to. 
This doesn't necessarily have to be done through html alone, but it is preferable.

Comment: is this what you need? http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Comment: Yep, but the text box should not appear when hovered over, only when you click on it. When hovered over it should highlight that text. (So it should not link to anything)

Comment: @Bentley4: You need to do it with some javascript and css, See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You may to do it with some javascript and CSS.

**CSS:**

```
a { padding: 2px 20px; background: #ccc; }
a:hover{ background: red; color: white; text-decoration:none; }
#msg { display: none; padding: 0 15px; background: #ccc; }​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="showinfo('msg')">Click Me</a>
    <span id="msg">Do you want this?</span>
</div>​
```

**Javascript:**

```
function showinfo(id){       
    var elemID = document.getElementById(id);        
    if( elemID.style.display == "inline-block") { elemID.style.display = "none"; } 
    else { elemID.style.display = "inline-block"; }    
}​
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/J9yXb/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS and JavaScript: Assign style display="none" to your info box in onload then change it to "block" or "inline" in onclick.